# How to get bounding box of 16*16 on an Image of 256*256

Tags: r, image-processing

I have 256*256 matrix,I have converted that to 256 blocks of 16*16.Now the challenge here is to put 16*16 (256 blocks) bounding on the image,so that I can get to know in which block a particular object lies.

I have a code to get the 256 blocks from the image .I don't know how to proceed from here?

code:

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/imag", pattern = "*.jpeg", full.names = TRUE)
list.files(pattern=".jpg$")
result={}
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
  x <- readJPEG(filenames[1])
  x= rgb_2gray(x)
  x <- resize(x, w = 256, h = 256)
  matsplitter<-function(M, r, c) {
    rg <- (row(M)-1)%/%r+1
    cg <- (col(M)-1)%/%c+1
    rci <- (rg-1)*max(cg) + cg
    N <- prod(dim(M))/r/c
    cv <- unlist(lapply(1:N, function(x) M[rci==x]))
    dim(cv)<-c(r,c,N)
    cv
  } 
  asa <-matsplitter(x,16,16) 
asa
result={}
y=c()
for (i in 1:length(asa[16,16,])) {
  y <- (as.vector(t(asa[,,i])))
  result <- data.frame(rbind(result,y))
}
result
```

Comment: First, define function before loop, not inside.

Comment: After the getting the 256 blocks only,I need to put those bounding boxes on images,not vice-versa

Comment: With `x <- readJPEG(filenames[1])` you are reading the first file **every** turn of the loop.